# Transferring data from USB flash drive directly to MyCloud Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, nas

I am trying to transfer a file from my USB flash drive to a MyCloud EX2 Ultra network attached hard drive without it having to go over the network. The file is 11GB so it is impractical to transfer it over a home network - it gives an estimated time of over eight hours, and I need bandwidth to do my work.

I have the hard drive mapped as a network drive in Windows 10, if that helps.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It isn't clear what the issue is, or why it's impractical to transfer it over the home network.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is that I am trying to transfer a file from a USB stick directly to the hard drive without having it go over the network. It's impractical to transfer it over the home network because it gave me an estimated time of over 8 hours and I need bandwidth to do my work.